# How to solve python Issue __import__(name) ImportError: No module named preferences

Tags: python, django

Stuck with issue as my project require Django==1.7.7 but couldn't proceed with this error.

```
 Library I have:
 Django==1.7.7
 django-browserid==2.0.2
 django-dynamic-preferences==1.7.1
 django-preferences==1.0.0
```

Comment: Please show the actual code causing the error.

Comment: Furthermore please do *not* use Django-1.7. Support ended on december 1, 2015 (!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know these packages from Django, specifically, but...

`ImportError: No module named <something>` always means the `import` command can't find the installed module in the paths within which it is looking, based on the Python settings.

All of the modules for Python are installed (for example with `pip install django-dynamic-preferences` into a `site-packages` (sometimes called `dist-packages`.) You can run the command ...

```
python -m site
```

...to see which paths it is using to find the `site-packages`

So, this error is being triggered because...

1. The package is not installed
2. The package is not being called correctly.

For example:

```
import preferences
```

...when maybe it is spelled wrong ...

```
import Preferences
```

... or you have the name wrong ...

```
import django-preferences
```

... or you're importing it in the wrong fashion ...

```
from preferences.models import Preferences
```

3. Finally, check your paths. On Linux/UNIX check `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME`. On Windows, check in the system paths (like [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94933-how-do-i-edit-my-system-path-in-windows))

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to find the root cause. while debugging I found I have two python versions installed(2 & 3) and the Django was looking at different paths for the packages, corrected and my project ran like a charm :)

Comment: @HimanshJoshi Glad to help. If you have two packages installed (probably a Python 2.7 and a 3.x) these usually also come with a `pip` (for installing to 2.7) and a `pip3` for installing to Python 3.x. This is not ALWAYS the case, but check for it :)